# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement is closed

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

My environment is using Spring Boot 3.1, Gradle, JPA and MSSQL.

Create membership registration logic, save final data using JPA's save method. The data is normally saved to the DB, but the error message below keeps coming out.

[Here is an error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEmrB.jpg)

Then, My code is here

**[Controller]**

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public String signUp(@Valid ManagersDto dto, Model model) {

        MessageAndRedirectDto messageDto;

        Optional<Managers> result = managersService.joinMember(dto);

        if(result.isEmpty()){
            messageDto = new MessageAndRedirectDto("Please wait a moment for approval.", "/", RequestMethod.GET, null);
        }else {
            messageDto = new MessageAndRedirectDto("The same ID already exists.", "/", RequestMethod.GET, null);
        }

        return messageAndRedirect.showMessageAndRedirect(messageDto, model);
    }
```

**[Service]**

```
 public Optional<Managers> joinMember(ManagersDto managersDto) {
        managersDto.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(managersDto.getPassword()));
        managersDto.setTelNo(commUtil.replaceHyphen(managersDto.getTelNo()));
        managersDto.setPhoneNo(commUtil.replaceHyphen(managersDto.getPhoneNo()));
        managersDto.setRole(UserRole.USER);
        managersDto.setStatus(UserStatus.WAITING);

        Optional<Managers> check = validationDuplicateUser(managersDto.toEntity());

        if(check.isEmpty()){
            try{
                managersRepository.save(managersDto.toEntity());
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return check;
    }
```

**[Repository]**

```
@Repository
public interface ManagersRepository extends JpaRepository<Managers, Long> {
    Optional<Managers> findByUserId(String userId);
}
```

For reference, whether or not there is a save method in the Repository, the result of an error is the same.

**[application.properties]**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:log4jdbc:sqlserver://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX;databaseName=DBName;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database=sql_server
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml
```

**[build.gradle]**

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.2.0.jre11'
implementation group: 'org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2', name: 'log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1', version: '1.16'
testImplementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.4.8'
```

As I asked above, the data is normally saved in the DB, but the error log is continuously being recorded. Because of this, it is difficult to perform actual error tracking. Thanks for your help.

It means that no error log occurs after saving.

Comment: Maybe something with the DriverSpy? Perhaps it doesnt handle things correctly, especially when you use some pool thingy

Comment: @siggemannen
First of all thank you. To create a log using logback,
I was able to get a search result that log4jdbc should be attached next to jdbc, such as net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy and jdbc:log4jdbc:sqlserver, to create a log through logback, so I used it as above.
And I searched a lot to find a solution, but I couldn't find an exact solution, so I asked for help here.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you use the "real" sql driver?

Comment: @siggemannen
Yes. it works correctly when I use just real sql driver. Then, when I use DriverSpy also it works to save. However, only error logs appear. I'm sure there must be an error somewhere, but I can't find it, and I want to make sure this part is resolved.

Comment: Looks like a bug. The logger you use looks like a really old project, so i have a feeling it's not well maintained, but i'm just guessing.

Comment: @siggemannen maybe I'll try changing the logging method. This is a case where I tried to apply a log method to the project, and after searching, I applied it because logback was searched a lot. thanks a lot for your comment.